# Save button is not working on custom widget

Tags: widgets, register-sidebar, customization

I created a custom widget according to [Widget API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Widgets_API) and it seems to work until I make changes. The save button is not triggered, this problem is only affecting this new widget.

Ps. The custom widget is also part of a `dynamic_sidebar` but every other widget works fine.

The button is enabled but not triggered.

[image: Save Button issue]

Edit. [Widget code](https://codeshare.io/2jJLDK)

Comment: Can you please here your custom widget code. so I can help you.

Comment: Sure, https://codeshare.io/2jJLDK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked code of [codeshare.io/2jJLDK](https://codeshare.io/2jJLDK) and found the issue. Please follow below instructions for fix this issue.

> In the form function, you have used input type as "url" for Link and as per rule of input type "url", it can't take "#" so you must use actual url with http/https like https://www.google.com/ for saving/updating widget link data.*

---

> If you want to save/update widget link data with "#" then you need to change input type as "text" like below

**From:**

```
<input type="url" name="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_name( 'link' ) ); ?>" id="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'link' ) ); ?>" class="widefat" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $link ) ?>">
```

**To:**

```
<input type="text" name="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_name( 'link' ) ); ?>" id="<?php echo esc_attr( $this->get_field_id( 'link' ) ); ?>" class="widefat" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $link ) ?>">
```